# Patriot P200 SSD for old Asus Zenbook

Tags: laptop, ssd

I've read that they are not so fast and also that reliability is a factor.

My notebook is 8 years old now so I guess that all these new fast SSD memory technologies are useless for me, but I need something that will not break down (and I loose all my data). I need it for media, video and photo production.

Can I trust the Patriot brand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging reliability of an SSD that hit the market less than a year ago is kind of difficult. And the actual question here (can I trust brand X) is much too broad to be answered conclusively. Patriot sells lots of different SKUs, at different price points, and for a different target audience.

So let's rather have a closer look at the actual model you are interested in, the P200 SSD. Here is a test of the 1TB model: https://www.techpowerup.com/review/patriot-p200-1-tb-ssd/11.html

While it mostly performs on par with similarly priced SSDs, It's biggest weakness is that it is a DRAM-less SSD. Which is why it struggles with intensive random read/write workloads. To a point where the difference becomes noticeable, even in real-world applications.
If we take a look at the prices for the 500GB model, the difference between the P200 and for example a Crucial MX500 is only about 3€ in my part of the world. Add another 8€, and you can already afford a Samsung 860 Evo.
In my personal opinion, the minimal price difference is not worth the potential performance difference for your applications.

tl;dr: invest a little bit more, and get different SSD with DRAM cache